# What kind of siloxane coating should I use on historical brownstone steps that is historically safe?

Tags: waterproofing, brick, masonry, stone

I'd like to reduce the amount of water soaking into my 120 year old brownstone steps and want to use something that won't run afoul of the landmarks historical commission or change the look in any real noticeable way.

Can I use any of the vapor permeable water resistant siloxane coatings from the big box stores or do i need something special?

[image]

Comment: If you have to deal with an outside source about what you can do, it usually best to ask them first.  Even if it is a PITA to do.

Comment: This is really a question that needs to go to the AHJ. We can make guesses, but they will be just that.

Comment: Those are literally sandstone steps? I would search for "sandstone matte sealer".

Comment: Hasn't water been soaking into the steps for 120 years already? For being that old, they look to be in great shape.